# Returning values to functions in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function=
{matmul(\a,\b)=
\def\product{}
\foreach \i in \b
{
\def\temp{}
\foreach \j in \a
{
\edef\temp{\temp,{\i}[0]*{\j}[0]+{\i}[1]*{\j}[1]+{\i}[2]*{\j}[2]}
}
\edef\product{\product,{\temp}}
}
}
]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is my function that takes two lists and operates on them. I don't know how to return the \product list back to the function. e.g.

```
output = matmul(list1,list2)
```

I would now want output to contain everything that \product contained

Comment: This is IMHO a highly nontrivial task to *really* solve the problem. There is at least one package, called `calculator`, which does some of these things. If you are absolutely sure that the user inserts nice matrices of matching dimensions, the `\foreach` approach can be made work. The main problem is to deal with all the special cases of wrong input. And then there is the aspect that you most likely do not want to stop at matrix multiplication, you may also want to transpose the matrices, compute determinants and/or invert them. Then the hell breaks loose if you want to allow sloppy input.

Comment: One of the technical reasons why your code does not work is that `\foreach` starts groups so changes made with `\edef` will not make it outside of the group. There could be more issues, hard to say because your code is not complete and there is no example. Nevertheless +1 because I'd very much interested in new solutions to this problem.

Comment: Have you considered a Lua(La)TeX solution? It would be way more doable than a pure (La)TeX solution, as there are a lot of matrix multiplication recipes in Lua wandering on the Web.

Comment: Schrodinger I can assure you that there will be no sloppy input.

Comment: @JairoAraujo how do you mean Lua(La)TeX?  How do I go about thei

Answer (score 2):

Your approach has the problem that `\foreach` does things in groups, and `\edef` only defines macros locally. So you could do `\xdef` instead. Because you may run out of name space and/or overwrite other macros, one usually does this with some temporary macros that have hilarious names and some `@` in to minimize the chance of doing harm. So the following monster does some matrix multiplication with `\foreach`. There are other ways which might be more elegant but also harder to comprehend. You need to feed the function `matmult` with the names of the macros (no `\`) that contain the matrices. The monster does some minimal sanity checks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{matmult}{2}{%
\begingroup%
\edef\pgfutil@tempA{\csname #1\endcsname}%
\edef\pgfutil@tempB{\csname #2\endcsname}%
\foreach \pgfutil@tempa [count=\pgfutil@tempc starting from 0] in \pgfutil@tempA
{\foreach \pgfutil@tempb [count=\pgfutil@tempd starting from 0] in \pgfutil@tempa 
{\xdef\pgfutil@tempe{\pgfutil@tempd}%
}\xdef\pgfutil@tempf{\pgfutil@tempc}%
}%
\edef\tmp@cols@A{\pgfutil@tempe}%
\edef\tmp@rows@A{\pgfutil@tempf}%
\foreach\pgfutil@tempa[count=\pgfutil@tempc starting from 0]in\pgfutil@tempB
{\foreach\pgfutil@tempb[count=\pgfutil@tempd starting from 0]in\pgfutil@tempa 
{\xdef\pgfutil@tempe{\pgfutil@tempd}%
}\xdef\pgfutil@tempf{\pgfutil@tempc}%
}%
\edef\tmp@cols@B{\pgfutil@tempe}%
\edef\tmp@rows@B{\pgfutil@tempf}%
 %\typeout{A:\the\numexpr\tmp@rows@A+1 x\the\numexpr\tmp@cols@A+1,B:\the\numexpr\tmp@rows@B+1\space x\the\numexpr\tmp@cols@B+1}%
\ifnum\tmp@rows@B=\tmp@cols@A
\foreach\pgfutil@tempa in{0,...,\tmp@rows@A}%
{\foreach\pgfutil@tempb in{0,...,\tmp@cols@B}%
{\foreach\pgfutil@tempc in{0,...,\tmp@cols@A}%
{\pgfmathparse{{\pgfutil@tempA}[\pgfutil@tempa][\pgfutil@tempc]*{\pgfutil@tempB}[\pgfutil@tempc][\pgfutil@tempb]}%
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempc=0\relax
 \xdef\pgfutil@tempd{\pgfmathresult}%
\else
 \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult+\pgfutil@tempd}%
 \xdef\pgfutil@tempd{\pgfmathresult}%
\fi
}%
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempb=0\relax
\xdef\pgfutil@tempe{\pgfutil@tempd}%
\else
\xdef\pgfutil@tempe{\pgfutil@tempe,\pgfutil@tempd}%
\fi
 %\typeout{curr row=\pgfutil@tempe}%
}%
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempa=0\relax
\xdef\pgfutil@tempf{{\pgfutil@tempe}}%
\else
\xdef\pgfutil@tempf{\pgfutil@tempf,{\pgfutil@tempe}}%
\fi
 %\typeout{a=\pgfutil@tempa:curr mat=\pgfutil@tempf}%
}%
\edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfutil@tempf}%
\else
\typeout{Dimensions do not match up.}%
\edef\pgfmathresult{}%
\fi
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
test:\edef\matA{{1,2,1},{-1,0,1},{1,2,3}}%
\edef\matB{{1,-2,0},{-1,2,0},{2,0,-3}}%
\pgfmathparse{matmult("matA","matB")}%
$A\cdot B=\pgfmathresult$\typeout{AxB=\pgfmathresult}
\end{document}
```

The typeout says

```
AxB={1.0,2.0,-3.0},{1.0,2.0,-3.0},{5.0,2.0,-9.0}
```

which is correct.

A slightly shorter variant is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Dim}{1}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfutil@tempcnta0%
\@for\pgfutil@tempa:=#1\do{\advance\pgfutil@tempcnta1}%
\edef\pgfmathresult{\the\pgfutil@tempcnta}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{matmult}{2}{%
\begingroup%
\edef\pgfutil@tempA{\csname #1\endcsname}%
\edef\pgfutil@tempB{\csname #2\endcsname}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp@rows@A}{Dim("\pgfutil@tempA")-1}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp@cols@A}{Dim("\pgfutil@tempA[0]")-1}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp@rows@B}{Dim("\pgfutil@tempB")-1}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp@cols@B}{Dim("\pgfutil@tempB[0]")-1}%
 %\typeout{A:\the\numexpr\tmp@rows@A+1 x\the\numexpr\tmp@cols@A+1,B:\the\numexpr\tmp@rows@B+1\space x\the\numexpr\tmp@cols@B+1}%
\ifnum\tmp@rows@B=\tmp@cols@A
\foreach\pgfutil@tempa in{0,...,\tmp@rows@A}%
{\foreach\pgfutil@tempb in{0,...,\tmp@cols@B}%
{\foreach\pgfutil@tempc in{0,...,\tmp@cols@A}%
{\pgfmathparse{{\pgfutil@tempA}[\pgfutil@tempa][\pgfutil@tempc]*{\pgfutil@tempB}[\pgfutil@tempc][\pgfutil@tempb]}%
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempc=0\relax
 \xdef\pgfutil@tempd{\pgfmathresult}%
\else
 \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult+\pgfutil@tempd}%
 \xdef\pgfutil@tempd{\pgfmathresult}%
\fi
}%
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempb=0\relax
\xdef\pgfutil@tempe{\pgfutil@tempd}%
\else
\xdef\pgfutil@tempe{\pgfutil@tempe,\pgfutil@tempd}%
\fi
 %\typeout{curr row=\pgfutil@tempe}%
}%
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempa=0\relax
\xdef\pgfutil@tempf{{\pgfutil@tempe}}%
\else
\xdef\pgfutil@tempf{\pgfutil@tempf,{\pgfutil@tempe}}%
\fi
 %\typeout{a=\pgfutil@tempa:curr mat=\pgfutil@tempf}%
}%
\edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfutil@tempf}%
\else
\typeout{Dimensions do not match up.}%
\edef\pgfmathresult{}%
\fi
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
test:\edef\matA{{1,2,1},{-1,0,1},{1,2,3}}%
\edef\matB{{1,-2,0},{-1,2,0},{2,0,-3}}%
\pgfmathparse{matmult("matA","matB")}%
$A\cdot B=\pgfmathresult$\typeout{AxB=\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{Dim("\matA[0]")}%
\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

One can go on and use more `\@for`s to avoid the `\xdef`s, if needed. It might be just get harder and harder to understand.

Comment: Good lord this a lot longer than I had expected... like is said in the other comment. Sloppy inputs aren't a problem because I'm the only one using it and of course I know how it works so sanity checks aren't necessary. This seems like a lot of code added on to my original code and I would really love to keep it as short as possible. Is there any way we could just return \product to matmul function?